# ReactNative on Android Package Server not running

Tags: android, react-native

Following this tutorial (https://mentormate.com/blog/react-native-components/) on React-Native which unfortunately only talks about IOS, I am trying to follow it in both IOS and Android.

I init the Employee app successfully and that creates project structure and both Android and IOS parts are created:

[image]

Following the tutorial in link above, I then opened the Employee.xcodeproj successfully using XCode, running it launches emulator just fine. Opening it in XCode and started React Packager and node server:

[image]

Then I tried opening Android project by opening the android folder in this project structure in Android Studio and that opened the project and built it successfully:

[image]

I tried running it on emulator first but emulator took way to long to start so I stopped that and connected my device through USB and then run it on the device but that shows me error like this:

[image]

I started learning about react-native few days ago and this is the very first example I am trying (for both IOS and Android).  So, I am very new to the subject and the error says that I need to package bundle correctly and that I need to run packager server.  As shown above, the server was run when I started IOS code from XCode but how do I package and run it from android studio?

Comment: what command you used to build the project for android?

Comment: Android Studio->Build->Rebuild Project from Android Studio menu

Comment: Try using `react-native run android` command . Make sure your device is connected with USB debugging on.

Comment: Thanks man, the command is react-native run-android actually and that worked.  Can you post as answer using correct command and I'll accept your answer.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that tutorial was for **ios** and it was not mentioned how to run in android.

To run the RN app in android , it must be build using `react-native run-android` command.

Comment: the command is actuall react-native run-android to be correct.  You can run it from terminal.  I went to my project folder in terminal and run it and it successfully deployed, thanks @YaShChaudhary

Comment: @pixel oh sorry ! ty :)

Answer (score 0):

I had also facing same issue. I resolve as given below :

1. Create folder "android/app/src/main/assets".
2. Run commands "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false
   --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
   android/app/src/main/res"
3. Now react-native run-android

This is working for me.